# Using Tomcat, Google Chrome cannot open localhost:8080 but Safari can

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I configured the Tomcat server on My Mac, set the port to be "8080" and started Tomcat, but I cannot open http://localhost:8080 with Chrome, and the Chrome return a message:"ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". However, When I tried "localhost:8080", it works! how can I solve this problem?

I've tried to find solutions on internet, someone says it maybe the problem of host file, I checked host file and found no problem. And I also tried http://127.0.0.1:8080, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try deleting your cache and disable the custom extensions on chrome, if any. This could be due to some security policies on chrome or some extension you are using

Answer (score 0):

First of all clear the problem, the problem is browser specific then check it in another browser like mozila or opera. if it is working on this browser but not in chrome then reset your chrome setting and clear all cache and local data.